# Why postgres decides randomly whether to use index or not in the same query, depending on the number of parameters in IN clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have the following table, which is partitioned based on a date range:

```
create table volume (
   id bigint, 
   event_ts timestamptz,
   lane integer,
   measure_line integer,
   volume integer,
) partition by range (event_ts)
```

I created a query which sums volumes for given lanes on some measure_line in 15 minutes intervals:

```
   with time_interval as (
      SELECT start_time, start_time + interval '15 minute' as end_time
      FROM generate_series( to_timestamp(1561496400), to_timestamp(1561582799), '15 minute'::interval) as start_time
   )
   select
     extract('epoch' from f.start_time)::int as start_time,
     coalesce(sum(volume), 0) as volume
   from volume v
   right join time_interval f
   on v.event_ts > f.start_time and v.event_ts < f.end_time
   and v.measure_line = 1
   and lane in (1,2,3,4)
   group by f.start_time, f.end_time
   order by start_time;
```

There is a number of partitions, one for each day:

```
...
volume_20190509
volume_20190510
volume_20190511
...
```

The following composite index is created for each partition:

```
volume_20190518_event_ts_lane_measure_line_idx
```

The result of the query looks like this:

```
start_time  volume_count
1561496400  58
1561497300  47
1561498200  43
1561499100  49
1561500000  39
1561500900  41
1561501800  47
1561502700  28
1561503600  41
```

Depending on the number of parameters in the IN clause for the lane column
the postgres is either using a sequential scan or the created index (I checked this with 'explain' clause). When it decides to use sequential scan the query slows at least 10 times! I can not understand this behavior! There is no obvious reason why it should not always use the created index. Do you have any idea why?

Postgres version: PostgreSQL 10.4

For example, when I pass only one value - where lane in (1) it uses sequential scan. When I pass more values - where lane in (1,2,3,4) it uses the created index.

EDIT:

Explain plan outputs

where lane in (1,2,3,4)
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

```
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=28395929.50..28395932.50 rows=200 width=28) (actual time=607.714..608.083 rows=96 loops=1)
        Group Key: f.start_time, f.end_time
        Buffers: shared hit=31658
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.42..26014632.00 rows=317506333 width=20) (actual time=1.607..514.124 rows=28630 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=31658
              ->  CTE Scan on time_interval f  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=0.057..0.977 rows=96 loops=1)
              ->  Append  (cost=0.42..22839.33 rows=317528 width=12) (actual time=1.068..3.957 rows=298 loops=96)
                    Buffers: shared hit=31658
                    ->  Index Scan using volume_20190324_event_ts_lane_measure_line_idx on volume_20190324 v  (cost=0.42..229.75 rows=3222 width=12) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=96)
                          Index Cond: ((event_ts > f.start_time) AND (event_ts < f.end_time) AND (measure_line = 1))
                          Filter: (lane = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
                          Buffers: shared hit=288
                    ->  Index Scan using volume_20190325_event_ts_lane_measure_line_idx on volume_20190325 v_1  (cost=0.42..228.74 rows=3162 width=12) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=96)
                          Index Cond: ((event_ts > f.start_time) AND (event_ts < f.end_time) AND (measure_line = 1))
                          Filter: (lane = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
                          Buffers: shared hit=288
                    ->  Index Scan using volume_20190326_event_ts_lane_measure_line_idx on volume_20190326 v_2  (cost=0.42..226.53 rows=3122 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=96)
                          Index Cond: ((event_ts > f.start_time) AND (event_ts < f.end_time) AND (measure_line = 1))
                          Filter: (lane = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
                          Buffers: shared hit=288
                    ->  Index Scan using volume_20190327_event_ts_lane_measure_line_idx on volume_20190327 v_3  (cost=0.42..229.48 rows=3157 width=12) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=96)
                          Index Cond: ((event_ts > f.start_time) AND (event_ts < f.end_time) AND (measure_line = 1))
                          Filter: (lane = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
                          Buffers: shared hit=288
                    ->  Index Scan using volume_20190328_event_ts_lane_measure_line_idx on volume_20190328 v_4  (cost=0.42..228.97 rows=3157 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=96)
                          Index Cond: ((event_ts > f.start_time) AND (event_ts < f.end_time) AND (measure_line = 1))
                          Filter: (lane = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
                          Buffers: shared hit=288
                    ->  Index Scan using volume_20190329_event_ts_lane_measure_line_idx on volume_20190329 v_5  (cost=0.42..230.02 rows=3227 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=96)
                          Index Cond: ((event_ts > f.start_time) AND (event_ts < f.end_time) AND (measure_line = 1))
                          Filter: (lane = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
                          Buffers: shared hit=288
...
```

where lane in (1) - took 5 minutes to complete

```
Sort  (cost=16986442.13..16986442.63 rows=200 width=28) (actual time=332823.872..332824.048 rows=96 loops=1)
  Sort Key: f.start_time
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
  Buffers: shared hit=24 read=113392, temp read=215935 written=2272
  CTE time_interval
    ->  Function Scan on generate_series start_time  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=0.045..0.482 rows=96 loops=1)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=16986418.98..16986421.98 rows=200 width=28) (actual time=332823.319..332823.630 rows=96 loops=1)
        Group Key: f.start_time, f.end_time
        Buffers: shared hit=24 read=113392, temp read=215935 written=2272
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..16386221.49 rows=80026333 width=20) (actual time=12066.893..332801.773 rows=7190 loops=1)
              Join Filter: ((v.event_ts > f.start_time) AND (v.event_ts < f.end_time))
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 68689930
              Buffers: shared hit=24 read=113392, temp read=215935 written=2272
              ->  CTE Scan on time_interval f  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=0.058..1.258 rows=96 loops=1)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..270371.58 rows=720237 width=12) (actual time=0.012..1865.908 rows=715595 loops=96)
                    Buffers: shared hit=24 read=113392, temp read=215935 written=2272
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..263253.39 rows=720237 width=12) (actual time=0.115..7524.225 rows=715595 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=24 read=113392
                          ->  Seq Scan on volume_20190324 v  (cost=0.00..2649.35 rows=7263 width=12) (actual time=0.107..83.392 rows=7205 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((measure_line = 1) AND (lane = 1))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 93285
                                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1141
                          ->  Seq Scan on volume_20190325 v_1  (cost=0.00..2644.50 rows=7276 width=12) (actual time=0.047..115.813 rows=7190 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((measure_line = 1) AND (lane = 1))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 93110
                                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1139
                          ->  Seq Scan on volume_20190326 v_2  (cost=0.00..2618.95 rows=7002 width=12) (actual time=0.049..77.066 rows=7105 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((measure_line = 1) AND (lane = 1))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 92225
                                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1128
                          ->  Seq Scan on volume_20190327 v_3  (cost=0.00..2644.05 rows=7190 width=12) (actual time=0.041..62.538 rows=7195 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((measure_line = 1) AND (lane = 1))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 93075
                                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1139
                          ->  Seq Scan on volume_20190328 v_4  (cost=0.00..2644.05 rows=7127 width=12) (actual time=0.026..44.041 rows=7200 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((measure_line = 1) AND (lane = 1))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 93070
                                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1139
                          ->  Seq Scan on volume_20190329 v_5  (cost=0.00..2643.90 rows=7236 width=12) (actual time=0.039..44.562 rows=7205 loops=1)
...
```

Comment: Can you add the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements and the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a query where a sequential scan is performed even though it is more expensive?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added the EXPLAIN outputs in both cases. I can not add the exact CREATE INDEX statements as they are generated by a code which I am not part of. But the index is a simple composite index on the following columns - evet_ts, lane, measure_line. The CREATE_TABLE is in the beginning of the question.

Comment: I only included the EXPLAIN output not the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS). Is it important to do the second one?

Comment: Yes, because that shows what really happens.

Comment: We need to have the `CREATE TABLE` statement of the others table(s) as well, atleast the one off `time_interval `

Comment: The EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) in the case with "where lane in (1)" took 5 minutes to complete, whereas in the case "where lane in (1,2,3,4)" took 2 seconds!

Comment: it might make more sense to use a delivered subquery where you select form the volume before joining and grouping.. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM volume ...) AS volume RIGHT JOIN ....` .. but not sure the volume table stucture which you have provided seams to be incomplete as the index specs are missing and looking in the explain there should be indexes in that table.

Comment: If you mean the CREATE_TABLE for the partition tables; I don't have it again. It is generated by a PSQL function written by another team. Do you think it might have any impact? Basically it just generates partition with one day event_ts intervals.

Comment: to me doesn't make any sense. Looking for one should use index too. Maybe https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for this question.