# The query processor ran out of internal resources | Workaround to use IN (tsql) with wildcards?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find a large amount of values in my database.

Below is what the data may look like:

```
0054321
54321
999
999  - HALLO?
54321 Hallo?
000054321
```

Since this is a one time thing, I thought I'd simply make a really long query searching through the data using OR and LIKE:

```
... WHERE ' ' + FLD1 + ' ' LIKE '%54321 %' 
OR        ' ' + FLD1 + ' ' LIKE '%999 %' 
OR ...
```

Imagine this but with 80k OR. In this case, SQL Server will run into the following issue:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

As a workaround, I read that you're supposed to declare a temporary TABLE and put your values in there, then search with 'IN' - but I have to search with LIKE so that I'll be able to use wildcards.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve or work around this issue?

I don't want to split the command into several commands using the same method.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: This seems a good case for using regular expressions in your select statement. Here are a few examples on how to search using expressions: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9112/precise-numerical-filtering-with-regular-expressions-for-tsql/

Comment: If this is `a one thing` I don't see the problem with split the conditions. And 80k `OR` is definitely not a normal thing so probably don't have normal solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a temporary table.

```
where exists (select 1
              from patterntable pt
              where ' ' + x.field1 + ' ' like pt.pattern
             )
```

`x` is the alias for whatever table the field comes from.

Or:

```
              where ' ' + x.field1 + ' ' like '% ' + pt.pattern + ' %'
```

depending on whether you want to store the wildcards or not.

Comment: what is x? and why you add spaces to `x.field1`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . The OP adds the spaces.  I just added them to the pattern because I think that is the intention.

Comment: I wonder if you saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837702/why-postgres-decides-randomly-whether-to-use-index-or-not-in-the-same-query-dep#comment100229072_56837702) I cant think one reason why is doing that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I add the spaces cause I need them for my pattern matching. 
I removed the first space since I only need the one after.  

I have Values like 
`000111 (WANT)
000111999 (DON'T WANT)
000111 TEXT (WANT)` - 

If I search for `%111%`, I would also get 0000111999 as a result, which I don't need. 
So I search for `%111[SPACE]%`, but now I wouldn't find entries that contain nothing but the Value like '000111', since it has no space. 
By Adding a space around every value, I can workaround this problem and my Pattern works as expected.